# Module Not Rendering on Frontend

Tags: magento-enterprise, configuration, blocks

I am trying to separate some business logic from my view.phtml file but can't seem to get the information to display when adding all the necessary files / directories for the module.

I created a new namespace in my **app/code/local** folder called ***Product*** and gave the module a name of ***FeaturedImage***.

This is my ***Product_FeaturedImage.xml*** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Product_FeaturedImage>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Product_FeaturedImage>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

---

Here are the contents of my ***config.xml*** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Product_FeaturedImage>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Product_FeaturedImage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <FeaturedImage>
                <class>Product_FeaturedImage_Block</class>
            </FeaturedImage>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

I am using my ***local.xml*** file to try and insert the block:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name='product.info'>
        <block type='FeaturedImage/callout' name='product.info.FeaturedImage.callout' as='product.view.FeaturedImage.callout' template='catalog/product/view/FeaturedImage/callout.phtml' />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

---

I am using the call -

```
<!-- BLOCK TESTING -->
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.info.FeaturedImage.callout') ?>
<!-- END NEW BLOCK TEST -->
```

I can see the comments when I view source but nothing is appearing in between.

I can also see the module is being recognized when I navigate to **system/configuration/advanced/disable modules output** but beyond that I am not seeing anything.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you created and implemented the block `Product_FeaturedImage_Block_Callout`?

Comment: Hi Simon -
Do you mean have I created the 'callout.phtml' file?
Sorry I am not quite understanding what you are asking.
Thanks!
Brendan

Comment: My question is if you created a file app/code/local/Product/FeaturedImage/Block/Callout.php which contains the class `Product_FeaturedImage_Block_Callout`? Because you refer to it in your local.xml. Whre is the content you want to show?

Comment: Hi Simon -
Here are the content of the block/callout.php file  <br/> 
`<?php
 
 class Product_FeaturedImage_Block_Callout extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
 {
  // CODE TO SPIT OUT PRODUCT INFO GOES HERE
 }
?>`

I currently haven't added any actual logic but am just trying to output some text from the callout.phtml file

Answer (score 2):

In your `local.xml` file you are defined your block like this

```
 <block type='FeaturedImage/callout' name='product.info.FeaturedImage.callout' as='product.view.FeaturedImage.callout' template='catalog/product/view/FeaturedImage/callout.phtml' />
```

Here the conversation between you and Magento somewhat happens like this

> You : Hi Magento, did you find my new module? I have configured it
>   just now
>
> Magento : No need to mention. I have already found your child. See
>   `System > Config > Advanced` for more info
>
> You :Thanks buddy... but I can't find my block here
>
> Magento : Really !! which is the block that you mentioned ?
>
> You : this is the block `FeaturedImage/callout` and i want this block
>   in product view page
>
> Magento : `FeaturedImage/callout` right ? Ya checking status. Please
>   wait
>
> You : OK
>
> Magento : **Did you defined this block in the backside of your
>   extension ?????????***

conversation ends.

This is the question that I am, gonna repeat to you.

In order to become your block valid you want that block defined in backside of your extension. The block that you referencing to Magento here is `Product_FeaturedImage_Block_Callout`. This should be defined as like this

Location: `app/code/local/Product/FeaturedImage/Block/Callout.php`

```
<?php
class Product_FeaturedImage_Block_Callout extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {


}
```

if this block is not defined, Magento will not render your block.

### EDIT

Other than that, I cant see any problems with your code...

So checkout these things

1. Make sure, you have inserted your local.xml file in the correct package/theme that is currently using. location goes like this `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout.xml`. You need to make sure this.
2. Make sure the template file that reside in correctly. ie in current `package/theme` directory. so the location here is `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/catalog/product/view/FeaturedImage/callout.phtml`.
3. Make sure your block is present in backend in the location top comments (comment of @simon) specified
4. More over clear all cache. before loading page again

Comment: +1 for Magento/You conversation :D Though he seems to have defined the block, see the comments under the question...

Comment: I didn't see that. i made an edit on answer. other than this, i am helpless

Answer (score 0):

you can also call the block directly using this code without using local.xml

```
 <?php echo $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('featuredimage/callout')->setTemplate('catalog /product/view/FeaturedImage/callout.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Hi Manikandan -
Thanks for the response, are there a benefits / negatives of doing it this way?  Just curious because everything I have seen states that it should be done through 'local.xml' and noticed that is the way magento does it natively.

Comment: We usually do it using local.xml for easy calling of block by name.. some times we can use this way too.. both have the same result

Comment: Hi Manikandan -

Should it be 
`$this->setLayout() ->createBlock('featured_image/callout')->setTemplate('catalog /product/view/FeaturedImage/callout.phtml')->toHtml();?>`

Comment: Yeah.. that's the code.. my editor cuts some codes while answering

Answer (score 0):

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <FeaturedImage>
                <class>Product_FeaturedImage_Block</class>
            </FeaturedImage>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

**should be**

```
   <global>
        <blocks>
            <featuredimage>
                <class>Product_FeaturedImage_Block</class>
            </featuredimage>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

and

```
 <block type='featuredimage/callout' name='product.info.featuredimage.callout' as='product.view.featuredimage.callout' template='catalog/product/view/featuredfmage/callout.phtml' />
```

According to your code block type is featuredimage/callout means

`featuredimage` means `Product_FeaturedImage_Block` as your config.xml code
then the block  type `featuredimage/callout` class is **Product_FeaturedImage_Block_Callout**
then pasted below  in view.phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.view.featuredimage.callout') ?>
```

**Alternative:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('featuredimage/callout')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/featuredfmage/callout.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer Amit, although I am still not seeing anything on the frontend.

Thanks!

Comment: try alternative solution